# error: label or instruction expected at start of line (nasm)

Tags: linux, nasm

i have just started learning nasm for my university and i don't know how to solve this problem. Here is the code:

```
SECTION .data
word: db 'напиши что-нибудь', 10
wordlen: EQU $-word

SECTION .bss
smth: resb 80

SECTION .text
GLOBAL _start
_start:

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,word
mov edx,wordlen
int 80h

mov eax,3
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,smth
mov edx,80
int 80h

mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

and these are the errors:

```
lab3-1.asm:2: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
lab3-1.asm:3: error: expression syntax error
lab3-1.asm:14: error: expression syntax error
```

would be glad to hear any advice

Comment: `word` is a keyword in NASM, for 16-bit operand size.  You can't use it as a symbol name.  It's like trying to use `int` or `short` as a function or variable name in C.

Comment: Search and replace `word` with `buf` all the way through.

Comment: @PeterCordes and @ david-c-rankin thank you. i changed it to "rolls" and it worked. :)